# popover not working in $.each(data, function (key, value)

Tags: javascript, html

In the if loop in $("tbody").append i am trying to add popover on inc_id parameter. Even though i have called the popover(); in ready function, its not working.
The hyperlink is getting added to the inc_id parameter but when i click on the hyperlink it does not show the popover content which i have added in  tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        td, th {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 8px;
}
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/api/incidents/",
            success: function(data) {
                $("tbody").empty();
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    var inc_Key = key;
                    var inc_id = value.id;
                    var inc_priority = value.priority;
                    var inc_status = value.status;
                    var inc_summary = value.summary;
                    var inc_group = value.group;
                    var inc_createdate = value.createdate
                    if(inc_Key==0){
                    $("tbody").append(
                       "<tr style='background-color:orange;color:white' ><td rowspan = 2><a href='#' data-toggle='popover' title='Popover Header' data-content='Some content inside the popover'>" + inc_id + "</a></td><td>" + inc_priority + "</td><td>" + inc_status + "</td><td>" + inc_group + "</td><td>" + inc_createdate + "</td></tr><tr style='background-color:orange;color:white'><td colspan = 4>" + inc_summary + "</td></tr>"
                    )}
                    else{
                    $("tbody").append(
                       "<tr><td rowspan = 2><a href='#' data-toggle='popover' title='Popover Header' data-content='Some content inside the popover'>" + inc_id + "</a></td><td>" + inc_priority + "</td><td>" + inc_status + "</td><td>" + inc_group + "</td><td>" + inc_createdate + "</td></tr><tr><td colspan = 4>" + inc_summary + "</td></tr>"
                    )
                    }
                })
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    }, 1000);
});
 </script>

</head>
<body>
<section class="pt100 pb100">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="vertical-align">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <table class="table table-condensed">
                       <thead style="background-color:steelblue;color:white">
                            <tr>
                                 <th>TICKET ID</th>
                                 <th>PRIORITY</th>
                                 <th>STATUS</th>
                                 <th>GROUP</th>
                                 <th>CREATE DATE</th>

                            </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                       </tbody>
                  </table>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest how can i make popover work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to initialize the plugin on elements before those elements exist.  This will catch any elements which may exist at that time, but not the ones you add later.

After adding your new elements to the table (in your `success` callback), select them to initialize the plugin on them as well:

```
$('tbody').empty();
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    // adding elements to the table as you already do
});
$('tbody [data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the provided HTML, this line:

`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();`

Will never work, since there is no `$('[data-toggle="popover"]')` element on `document.ready()` (you're adding it afterwards through AJAX).

I suggest you move the above line to after the AJAX completes, like so:

```
$("tbody").append(
   "<tr style='background-color:orange;color:white' ><td rowspan = 2><a href='#' data-toggle='popover' title='Popover Header' data-content='Some content inside the popover'>" + inc_id + "</a></td><td>" + inc_priority + "</td><td>" + inc_status + "</td><td>" + inc_group + "</td><td>" + inc_createdate + "</td></tr><tr style='background-color:orange;color:white'><td colspan = 4>" + inc_summary + "</td></tr>"
)}
else{
$("tbody").append(
   "<tr><td rowspan = 2><a href='#' data-toggle='popover' title='Popover Header' data-content='Some content inside the popover'>" + inc_id + "</a></td><td>" + inc_priority + "</td><td>" + inc_status + "</td><td>" + inc_group + "</td><td>" + inc_createdate + "</td></tr><tr><td colspan = 4>" + inc_summary + "</td></tr>"
)
}
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```